# Is there moderation on images that are uploaded but not posted?

Tags: discussion, image

I realised today that I could upload an image into the question box, and copy the web address, and delete the link from the question - **and the image remains at that link**. In effect, I could use SO as a hosting site, and some people may exploit this, and host less desirable images on the site - without anyone knowing, because they never posted the question.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsqOH.png) - uploaded at about 2100 BTC (2000 UTC)

Possibly bug?

Comment: Yup, I've used this before when I needed to put an image in the comments, since SE uses their own special imgur service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE doesn't sort of doesn't host the images, Imgur does:
[image]
<sup>from [`http://stack.imgur.com/`](http://stack.imgur.com/)</sup>

Also, it may be more likely that it checks if the links are on the SE sites, or how many request for each image there are before deleting them - so as you have linked that image, it may not be deleted.

**Edit:**
 From [Imgur FAQ](https://imgur.com/faq#long):

> As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they
>   will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to
>   create more space for newer images.

I would of thought Imgur would use something like this, as people can often upload pictures and then not link/use them - Imgur have to cope with increasing amounts of images, so they get rid of unneeded ones.

Also, on deleting pics:

- [Imgur FAQ - Can I delete an image after I upload it?](https://imgur.com/faq#delete)
- [Imgur - Removal Request](https://imgur.com/removalrequest)

From the point of of moderation then, SE mods may be able to log in and request the removal of images.

Answer (score 8):

I answered this on Meta Stack Exchange at [Potential to abuse Imgur?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137057/115866). The short answer is, we don't currently auto-delete, but because we could start doing that at any time, and given that you can get the identical image hosting with a free Imgur account where *you* would stay in control instead of us, the potential for abuse is low because it just wouldn't make a lot of sense to do it.

Comment: +1 for mention low potential abuse.

Answer (score 2):

Logic would dictate that stats are being kept for files that are loaded and that files that do not get loaded after x minutes get removed.

Comment: I would hope so, but it still hasn't gone - I'll update my question with my example image.